# Dubai transit - is there a 48 hour visa on arrival for Indian citizens?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dubai, visas-on-arrival, vfs-global

On my return journey along with family from the UK, I have a layover of more than 12 hours at Dubai airport. I want to use this time to visit the city and sightsee. I am booked on Emirates right through the journey on all 4 legs of the trip and there is no change of terminal. We are all Indian citizens so I am aware I need a transit visa to enter the city of Dubai.

I spoke to customer service at Emirates and the person mentioned that I can get a 48 hour visa on arrival at Dubai airport for this purpose. Can somebody confirm the same? Have any Indian travellers through Dubai availed this service recently and the info is valid?

I was under the impression that as an Indian citizen I am not eligible for a visa on arrival at Dubai and I needed to arrange for it before the journey. I will have a valid UK visa stamped in my passport upon arrival at Dubai.

Another question - if I apply for the visa through VFS, do I need to supply proof of accommodation in Dubai? Since I plan to spend about 8 hours in the city, I don't have any hotel booking.

Thanks for your responses and inputs.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it is specific to the 48 hr visa on arrival for Indians at Dubai airport. It is not about the need for a transit visa which is quite clear. The other question has no mention of the 48 hours visa.

Comment: "Transit visa" also refers to a visa that allows you to access a country during a layover. There is a section regarding that in the link.

Comment: @Vikky Or just search the relevant Emirates page.